# Generate dependency library in pod

Tags: ios, bash, static-libraries, cocoapods

I have made a Pod which I want to include as dependency in my XCode Project.

Everthing worked good. But I cannot make this pod public because pod uses a `static library` which is around `300 mb`.

Now I am thinking to write a `script` so that library only get generates when pod gets installed.

I have source code for that library so I can easily build the library on post-installation of pods.

How can I do this now?? Anybody can give me a hint to write such script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for it and finally I got the solution is to use 
    prepare_command 
of cocoapod

I made the script file `buildScripter.sh` (in my case)
and then

```
spec.prepare_command= "sh  pathToScript/buildScripter.sh"
```

which solved the problem.